# ASCII sum value of all characters

Tags: java

why does my code fail? It fails on the chatAt function upon the second rotation of the for loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <n ; i++) {{
            String letter = scanner.nextLine();

            char valueOf = letter.charAt(i);
            int valueto = (int)valueOf;
            sum += valueto;
        }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);

    }
}
```

Comment: What inputs did you give it?

Comment: 5 , A, b, C, d, E

Comment: How is it failing? You need to explain what you are trying to do.  Do you really want to read in a line inside the loop?  What sum did you expect for your input?

Comment: Ask yourself: what is the second letter of the string "b"?

Comment: Oh I see, because it tries to read additional symbols, when all I needed to do was to read letter.charAt(0) since the position is not chaning, got it, ty vm dratenik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is getting the character from `i`th index, which will throw an index out of range error, as `i` increases continuously throughout the loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <n ; i++) {{
            String letter = scanner.nextLine();
            // Set charAt 0th index to read the character from the input 
            char valueOf = letter.charAt(0);
            int valueto = (int)valueOf;
            sum += valueto;
        }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);

    }
```